# How to differentiate data / voice usage for dual sim in Android

Tags: android, dual-sim

I am developing application which calculates data and voice usage from user's android phone.
Issue I am facing is differentiating this data according to numbers in dual sim phones.
(e.g. If I make call from SIM 1 then voice usage should be mapped against corresponding number)

I have searched in SO for this kind of code snippet but had no luck.

Is this possible in Android programmatically by any means ? 
If yes, then what could be best possible solution for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no support for dual slim as for today. Thats mean - there is no any official public API available.

[Issue 14799:   Dual SIM cards supporting](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=14799)

Comment: @silwar are you able to solve the issue. i am stuck with the same becuse call logs gives all accumulative data ,,how to seggregate call logs for dual sim